# Metric on the unit cube

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the sup norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$. Let $Y=\{x\in X: \|x\|_{\infty}=1\}$. For $x,y\in Y,y\neq -x$ define $d(x,y)$ to be the arc length of  the path  $$Y\cap \{\lambda x+\mu y: \lambda\ge 0, \mu\ge 0\}.$$ Define $d(x,-x)=4$. Note that the arc lengths are computed using the sup norm. My question is:  Does $d$ define a metric on $Y$?
A related question was answered in [Shortest path on unit sphere under $\|\cdot\|_\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79008/shortest-path-on-unit-sphere-under-cdot-infty)

Comment: In fact the answer can be found in the given link. Let $A=(1,3/4,1/4), B=(3/4,1,3/4), C=(1,1,1/2)$ and $M=(1,1,4/7)$. Then
$d(A,C)=1/4, d(C,B)=1/4$ and $d(A,B)=d(A,M)+d(M,B)=4/7$. So 
$d(A,C)+d(C,B)<d(A,B)$, proving that $d$ is not a metric.

Comment: TCL: Why not post an answer?

Comment: @TCL I'm not sure what the relevance is more than a year later, but it's better to ask a new question instead of editing in this case -- your edit made this question wholly different from its original.

Answer (score 2):

An answer [from the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108023/metric-on-the-unit-cube#comment252716_108023):

> In fact the answer can be found in the given link [[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79008/shortest-path-on-unit-sphere-under-cdot-infty) -- LF].
>
> Let:
> $$A=(1,3/4,1/4),\ B=(3/4,1,3/4),\ C=(1,1,1/2)\text{ and }M=(1,1,4/7).$$ Then:
> $$d(A,C)=1/4,\ d(C,B)=1/4\text{ and }d(A,B)=d(A,M)+d(M,B)=4/7.$$ So $d(A,C)+d(C,B)<d(A,B)$, proving that $d$ is not a metric.